# Django - How can i resize the svg in the html template

Tags: python, django, matplotlib, svg, resize

I just created a matplot figure from a csv in django (line graph) and rendering it to the html template and I can't modify its dimensions

```
imgdata = io.StringIO()
        fig.savefig(imgdata, format='svg')
        imgdata.seek(0)
        data = imgdata.getvalue()
        return data
    data = isolate(selected_loc)
    return render(request, 'hello.html', {'data': data, 'locations' : list(locations)})
```

html template

```
<div class="figure" style="">{{ data|safe }}</div>
```

i tried styling the div in css

```
.figure {
        width: 40%;
        height: 500px;
      }
```

and it doesnt working only the div container expands but not the svg that just rendered

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1a2tZ.png)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`xml.etree.ElementTree` is a python library that allows you to parse and manipulate svgs.

Side note -> IDK what's happening with the 2 return statements, but I am going to assume I am ignorant as opposed to you being wrong, because presumably your svg is being shown.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from io import StringIO

imgdata = io.StringIO()
        fig.savefig(imgdata, format='svg')
        imgdata.seek(0)
        data = imgdata.getvalue()
        return data
    data = isolate(selected_loc)
    return render(request, 'hello.html', {'data': data, 'locations' : list(locations)})


tree = ET.parse(imgdata)
root = tree.getroot()

# whatever the namespace is typically "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
# elements are the elements you are looking for
for e in root.findall("{namespace}elements"):
    e.attrib["attribute_to_set"] = ""

root.attrib["height"] = "100%"
root.attrib["width"] = "100%"

# tree.write() saves the file so you can write it to a BytesIO or StringIO
# the below should work.
tree.write(imgdata)
```

Your css should also work, but I think you should be attaching it to the svg itself and not the container. There is a chance that some style is taking precedence over the style you're trying to apply, so you could always add an `!important` at the end of it, like so, `border: solid black 1px !important;` to rule that out.

---

Given the information above, you have 2 options; Either use the CSS below or use the `etree` code and remove the `svg {...}` css I have below.

If you don't have an id attached to the svg itself, you would have to select it:

```
svg
{
    width: 100%;
    /*height: 100%;*/
}
.container
{
    width: 40%;
    height: 500px;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try it like this .

```
<svg width="100" height="100" viewBox="0 0 100 100" xmlns="your path"></svg>
```

Comment: This might be the right answer but the code is not valid SVG and it would be great with an explanation.